# how to get this result ["a1","a2",..."a20"] in ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays

`("a1".."a5").to_a`

result:["a1","a2","a3","a4","a5"]

why doesn't ("a1".."a20").to_a put ["a1","a2",..."a20"]?

I want to get your help ,thanks!

Comment: It will output `["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6", "a7", "a8", "a9", "b0", "b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "b5", "b6", "b7", "b8", "b9", "c0", "c1", "c2", "c3"...."zz7", "zz8", "zz9"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its generate by ASCII order of every string, you can try `('1'..'z').to_a` to see what happend. So your code will generate every posible that can. If you want to get `['a1', 'a2', .. 'a20']`, use

```
(1..20).to_a.map {|i| "a#{i}" }
```

Comment: @user3673267 Please mark this answer as "accepted" if you feel like it answered your question :)